# Is there a way to get the output of a function that translates a string to be in the same order as the input?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Sorry if the title was confusing. The exercise I'm working on is to write a function which takes two arguments: a dictionary which maps Swedish words to English, and a string corresponding to a Swedish sentence. The function should return a translation of the sentence into English

My function works well regarding the translation, but the output it produces is in the wrong order.

For example, the following argument, consisting of a dictionary and a string in Swedish (Eng: "A fine monkey")

```
translate_sentence({'en': 'a', 'fin': 'fine', 'apa': 'monkey'}, 'en fin apa')
```

should return

```
'a fine monkey'
```

but instead it returns

```
'a monkey fine'
```

Here is the script for the function:

```py
def translate_sentence(d, sentence): 
    result = []                     
    delimiter = ' '                 
    s = sentence.split()            
    for word in d:                        
        if word in sentence and word in d:
            d_word = (d[word])
            result.append(d_word)
    for word in s:                          
        if word in s and word not in d:
            s_word = word
            result.append(s_word)
    return delimiter.join(result)
```

As I said before, the problem is that the function returns the translated string with the words in the wrong order. I know that python dictionaries aren't ordered, isn't there some way to get the output to be in the same order as sentence?

Comment: As a side note, dicts in Python 3.6+ are ordered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6/39980744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner seems to work fine. Lookup each word in the dictionary and join in the same order as the input sentence.

```
def translate_sentence(d, sentence): 
    return ' '.join(d.get(word, word) for word in sentence.split())
```

Example:

```
>>> translate_sentence({'en': 'a', 'fin': 'fine', 'apa': 'monkey'}, 'en fin apa')  
'a fine monkey'
>>>
```

Comment: I handled that case in my answer. Please check If it makes sense

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Cool. handled it in mine too - in a slightly more succinct way :)

Comment: Great +1 for the succinctness, Hope I get a +1 for my idea to you too :)

Answer (score 1):

We check the value for each key, where key is a word in the string, and if we don’t find it, we use the original word

```
def translate_sent(d, s): 
    return ' '.join(d[word] if word in d else word for word in s.split())

>>> translate_sent({'en': 'a', 'fin': 'fine', 'apa': 'monkey'},        'en fin apa')  
'a fine monkey'
>>> translate_sent({'en': 'a', 'fin': 'fine'}, 'en fin apa')  
‘a fine apa’
```